# OpenIdDict: An email link to identity server for registering a user

Tags: registration, openiddict, identity-server

I have a react application that connect to asp.net Core api with separated identity server (openiddict).

I want to send an email with registration link to some user so the user can register themselves and create the user in identity server.

Do I just expose my identity server url with registration path in the email?